# php classname issues with Xenapi

Tags: php, xen

I installed Xenapi using composer in my project directory. I had namespace errors. which I resolved using

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

I am using php7.0 and apache2 on Ubuntu16.04. My code is:

`

```
    <?php
        require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
        use Sircamp\Xenapi\Xen as Xen;
    $ip = "172.31.100.52";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root@123";

    $xen = new Xen($ip,$username,$password);
?>
```

`

The Error is:

> Fatal error: Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/respect/validation/library/Rules/String.php on
>   line 4

A solution proposed says about changing class name other than string.Obviously, I cannot change the name everywhere in the Xenapi.
What other solution is possible.

Comment: This is not a problem caused by Xenapi, it comes from [this library](https://github.com/Respect/Validation)

Comment: Note that this was [fixed](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/commit/255269bfb3ec48e7538b3153eaea65ae0c8a8a85) a (long) while ago. Xenapi merely needs to update its dependencies!

Comment: So how should I resolve this problem for myself now ?

Comment: You could create a pull request on github to update the dependencies, or you could open an issue an ask the author to do so.

Comment: thanks! I downgraded my version to php 5.6 and it worked.